# Async and mapAsync - Achieving parallelism in akka streams - reactive kafka

Tags: akka, akka-stream, reactive-kafka

I am currently working with akka streams and building a reactive application. My understanding so far is when `async` boundary is set,

Each stage(Flow) runs in an actor. Is that true?

Calling `mapAsync` is similar to applying `async` to the flow?

Ideally, I would have bunch of graphs and would want each to run parallelly in an actor, which helps to scale.

Additional information:

I am implementing something with reactive kafka, Would like to know how kafka topic consumption is load balanced. ie: If I have 20 partitions, if I am using `plainPartitionSource` and build a graph, does it create that many consumer actors?

If there are going to be 20 consumer actors(equal to 20 partitions for a specific topic it is consuming to), then there will ideally be 20 graphs. Materializing the graphs, I would want it to run in different actors.

In short, I want full parallelism depending on the number of partitions, from consumption to processing it.

Hope my question is clear.

EDIT:

```
val consumerGroup =
  Consumer.committablePartitionedSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("topic1"))
//Process each assigned partition separately
consumerGroup.map {
  case (topicPartition, source) =>
    source
      .via(business)
      .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.both)
      .run()
}

.mapAsyncUnordered(maxPartitions)(_._2) 
//maxPartitions create that 
//many actors here to materialize each of the internal graph in 
//separate actors?

.runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: Usually, each time you call `run()`a new actor for the stream will be created so you should be fine if you let enough elements come through. So you are right that `maxPartitions` will actually limit the amount of streams running in parallel because it provides the demand that will pull elements into the `map` stage above. It would be even clearer if you would replace the `map(...).mapAsyncUnordered` combo with a single `mapAsyncUnordered`.